# How to set multiple mails in symfony 4 using swiftmailer-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using swiftmailer-bundle for sending emails from my applications

I have added this in env.

> MAILER_URL=gmail://mailExample@mail.com:mypassword@localhost?encryption=tls&auth_mode=oauth

And this when i need to sent the email from controller

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message($objet))
                ->setFrom('mailExample@mail.com','example')
                ->setTo(exemple2@mail.com)
                ->setBody("test")
                )
```

My question is how to add another mail?, i need to use more than one mail

Can i add two lines of MAILER_URL in env. ??

Comment: do you mean send to more than one email address?

Comment: @tim i mean i want add my two emails, for example i want to add this two Mails 
 ->setFrom('FirstMail@mail.com','example') and
 ->setFrom('secondMail@mail.com','example')

Comment: I mean more source not only one mail

Comment: you cant have 2 from addresses in one email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the official documentation on using multiple mailers.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#using-multiple-mailers

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: first_mailer
    mailers:
        first_mailer:
            url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
        second_mailer:
            url: '%env(SECOND_MAILER_URL)%'
```

```php
// returns the first mailer
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.first_mailer');

// returns the second mailer
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer');
```

Comment: I haven't understand the doc, where i will add the mail and the password

Comment: I've updated my answer to be a little more clear. In the same place you've set your MAILER_URL environment variable, add a second variable called SECOND_MAILER_URL. It will be picked up by the configuration above.